# Need to save Outlook Inbox Selected mail to local drive using Java

Tags: grails, groovy, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am using Groovy & Grails Project. Currently I need to save outlook selected mail. Anyone have idea on it. Kindly share links or code snippet.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Tried with Office.js to access mailbox item. But external office.js not fully loaded it showing anonymous while intializing js.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 Office.initialize = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () { 
     var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
     var subject = item.subject;
   });
 };

Comment: To confirm, are you writing an Outlook web addins discussed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview? office.js is intended for for Outlook web addins.